# How to create exception for Adobe Acrobat in windows

Tags: windows, exception, adobe

After starting adobe Acrobat , files are created whose size exceeds the quotas,
To avoid this i need to create an exception in %Userprofile%
How do i do that ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Go to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection. - Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions. - Select Add an exclusion, and then select from files, folders, file types, or process.